# Issue displaying PMI annotations in Autodesk Viewer for assembly files

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk, solidworks, step

I am facing an issue when trying to display PMI (Product and Manufacturing Information) annotations in Autodesk Viewer for SolidWorks assembly files. I have an assembly file created in SolidWorks, where I added dimensions using the MBD extension. I exported this file to STEP AP 242 format, which supports these PMI annotations, and was able to view them correctly in eDrawings. However, when opening the same file in Autodesk Viewer, the PMI information does not appear.

Interestingly, I noticed that the PMI annotations are displayed correctly in Autodesk Viewer for files that are not assembly files. There seems to be some specific issue when displaying PMI annotations in assembly files in Autodesk Viewer.

Has anyone else encountered this issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve it? I am puzzled as to why the PMI annotations are not being displayed in Autodesk Viewer for SolidWorks assembly files, considering that the STEP AP 242 format is supported. Any help or insights you can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: sorry for letting you wait. Since you mentioned Assembly, have you tried to package the model and other necessary files to zip, and send this zip to be translated by APS? When you viewed STEP in eDrawings, is that a single STEP file or also with other associated files? If zip does not work, please send us a copy of test files at aps.help@autodesk.com. We will look into it.

Comment: It's works for to show a assembly, but the problem is that the PMI (Dimensions, Gtols) is not showed. The PMI is just showed for the Parts from the step AP242 file.
Sorry for the wait.